# How much time will it take me to watch the .hack series?

Tags: .hack

I'd like to give .hack a go, however I have very limited time in my schedule so I often avoid picking series with too many episodes.

I would like to know :

- How much time does it take to watch **everything** ?
- How much time does it take to watch **main part** of the series?

Comment: What is your definition of to much episodes? IIRC, the whole of .hack, including ova's exists of a mere 75 episodes

Comment: are you also including the games which bridge the gaps between the last 2 episodes of SIGN (first 4 games) and ROOTS (G.U games)? which ultimately is the bulk of the story of the First Twilight and the AIDA Incident

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To watch everything including ova's, movies and the likes would take you **2091** minutes ***(34.85 hours)*** spread over 83 epsiodes. This would cover:

- .hack roots
- .hack//Sign
- .hack//Gift
- .hack//Unison
- .hack//Tasogare no Udewa Densetsu
- .hack//Quantum
- .hack//Liminality
- .hack//G.U. Returner
- .hack//G.U. Trilogy
- .hack//Intermezzo
- .hack//G.U. Trilogy: Parody Mode
- .hack//The Movie: Sekai no Mukou ni
- .hack//Versus: The Thanatos Report
- .hack//Tasogare no Udewa Densetsu: Offline de Aimashou
- .hack//Quantum: Sore ike! Bokura no Chimuchimu-chan!!

And if we take a look at [How to start the .hack series and its viewing order?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13645/how-to-start-the-hack-series-and-its-viewing-order?rq=1) we can determine that the only true cannon series are:

- .hack//SIGN
- .hack//Liminality
- .hack//Roots

Which is only **1380** minutes ***(23 hours)*** spread over 56 episodes